# AutoHotKey script to toogle CTRL and timer

Tags: autohotkey

I can't get this script to stop when I hit `F7`

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

F7::
    SetTimer, Spam, off
    SendInput, {Ctrl Up}
return

F8::
    SendInput, {Ctrl Down}
    SetTimer, Spam, 1000
return

Spam: 
   Click
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to put a wildcard before the `F7`.

This is because when `CTRL` was down, it was impossible for me to hit just `F7`, because `CTRL+F7` was being sent instead.

Correct script:

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

*F7::
    SetTimer, Spam, off
    SendInput, {Ctrl Up}
return

F8::
    SendInput, {Ctrl Down}
    SetTimer, Spam, 1000
return

Spam: 
   Click
return
```